# How works login function in cake php?

Tags: authentication

Login functionality is not working in cake php

I generate UsersController.php

```
     public function login() {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }
     }

     public function add() {
         if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->User->create();
        $this->request->data['User']['password'] = md5($this->request->data['User']['password']);
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
     }
   }
```

My model file Users.php

```
            <?php 
            App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');

            class User extends AppModel {
                public $validate = array(
                    'username' => array(
                    'required' => array(
                        'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                        'message' => 'A username is required'
                      )
                          ),
                         'password' => array(
                         'required' => array(
                            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                         'message' => 'A password is required'
                      )
                       ),
                     'role' => array(
                      'valid' => array(
                          'rule' => array('inList', array('admin', 'author')),
                                  'message' => 'Please enter a valid role',
                          'allowEmpty' => false
                       )
                      )
                  );

                   public function beforeSave($options = array()) 
                   {
                        if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) 
                        {
                         $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
                    }

                        return true;
                   }
               }
               ?>
```

My view file is Uesrs/login.ctp

```
           <div class="users form">

               <?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
               <?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>

              <fieldset>

                  <legend><?php echo __('Please enter your username and password'); ?></legend>
                  <?php echo $this->Form->input('username');
                     echo $this->Form->input('password');
                  ?>

               </fieldset>

              <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Login')); ?>

           </div>
```

When i run this code it tells "Invalid username or password, try again" .

But I enter right user name and password.

Why this issue is coming?

Please help me. I new for Cake Php.

Comment: Could you please post your complete code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.
Are you sure about the username and password? Might check it again in the DB?

```
   public function login()
      {
      if( $this->request->is('post') )
      {
        App::Import('Utility', 'Validation');
        if( isset($this->data['User']['username']) && Validation::email($this->data['User']['username']) )
        {
          $this->request->data['User']['email'] = $this->data['User']['username'];
          $this->Auth->authenticate['Form'] = array('fields' => array('username' => 'email'));
        }

        if( ! $this->Auth->login() )
        {
          $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }
        else
        {
          $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: User name and password correct in DB. But when we pass data through login that time password is shown in encrypt and in DB also saved password in encrypt. But they are different. why Both password are showing different answer. I used only username and password.

Comment: When they are different encrypted; then you're not using the correct password.